# limitPage() with some JOINs in Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, select, join

Programmers.
I have the next SELECT statement, created using Zend Framework:

```
$select = $this->select()
    ->from('post')
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->join('post_category', 'post.category_id = post_category.id', array(
        'category_name' => 'name',
        'category_name_key' => 'name_key'))
    ->joinLeft('post_comment', 'post_comment.post_id = post.id', array(
        'comment', 'comment_date_creation' => 'date_creation'))
    ->limitPage(2, 10);
```

But it is one problem in limitPage(). For example I have 100 rows in `post` table. And after JOINing SELECT returns (for example) 200 rows. But I should `LIMIT` only rows from the `post` table with all relations. How can I do it in ONE query using Zend Framework?

Comment: Don't care if this load 100 or 200 rows, even if they are not used, if you think it's worth to do some optimization, try out to use a good caching system first.

Comment: What? I have a good caching. But my question is another. If you don't have an answer,  ПНХ.

Comment: Well, as Tomáš Fejfar said, it's not possible to do that in SQL, why do you want to limit the result then?

Comment: Haha. I have done it with help of ONE query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real question is how would you do it in plain SQL?! IMO you can't do that in SQL. And that is the very reason you can't do that using Zend_Db_Select either ;) Update your post with the plain SQL query you would use and I would tell you how to write that using Zend_Db.